# OLED display wrong (using SPI )

Tags: arduino-uno, spi

I can't figure out where I doing wrong

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35NqOANmgUE

This is my question in videos

[image]

The both of two connect the same pin

(so the right display result is the correct  OLED)

My connecting table  (using SPI )

GND              gnd

VCC              5V

D0(OLED_CLK)     10

D(OLED_MOSI)     9

RES(OLED_RESET)  13

D/C(OLED_DC)     11

CS（OLED_CS）    12

but the left OLED doesn't have the "RES" pin
(so I didn't connect it)

the left OLED just display the upper part 
(and its the position of display picture is also wired ,too)

this is my code

```
/*********************************************************************
This is an example for our Monochrome OLEDs based on SSD1306 drivers
This example is for a 128x64 size display using SPI to communicate
4 or 5 pins are required to interface

Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code, 
please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing 
products from Adafruit!

Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada  for Adafruit Industries.  
BSD license, check license.txt for more information
All text above, and the splash screen must be included in any redistribution
*********************************************************************/

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

// If using software SPI (the default case):
#define OLED_MOSI   9
#define OLED_CLK   10
#define OLED_DC    11
#define OLED_CS    12
#define OLED_RESET 13
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_MOSI, OLED_CLK, OLED_DC, OLED_RESET, OLED_CS);

/* Uncomment this block to use hardware SPI
#define OLED_DC     6
#define OLED_CS     7
#define OLED_RESET  8
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_DC, OLED_RESET, OLED_CS);
*/

#define NUMFLAKES 10
#define XPOS 0
#define YPOS 1
#define DELTAY 2

#define LOGO16_GLCD_HEIGHT 16 
#define LOGO16_GLCD_WIDTH  16 
static const unsigned char PROGMEM logo16_glcd_bmp[] =
{ B00000000, B11000000,
  B00000001, B11000000,
  B00000001, B11000000,
  B00000011, B11100000,
  B11110011, B11100000,
  B11111110, B11111000,
  B01111110, B11111111,
  B00110011, B10011111,
  B00011111, B11111100,
  B00001101, B01110000,
  B00011011, B10100000,
  B00111111, B11100000,
  B00111111, B11110000,
  B01111100, B11110000,
  B01110000, B01110000,
  B00000000, B00110000 };

#if (SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT != 64)
#error("Height incorrect, please fix Adafruit_SSD1306.h!");
#endif

void setup()   {                
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // by default, we'll generate the high voltage from the 3.3v line internally! (neat!)
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC);
  // init done

  // Show image buffer on the display hardware.
  // Since the buffer is intialized with an Adafruit splashscreen
  // internally, this will display the splashscreen.
  display.display();
  delay(2000);

  // Clear the buffer.
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw a single pixel
  display.drawPixel(10, 10, WHITE);
  // Show the display buffer on the hardware.
  // NOTE: You _must_ call display after making any drawing commands
  // to make them visible on the display hardware!
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw many lines
  testdrawline();
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw rectangles
  testdrawrect();
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw multiple rectangles
  testfillrect();
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw mulitple circles
  testdrawcircle();
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw a white circle, 10 pixel radius
  display.fillCircle(display.width()/2, display.height()/2, 10, WHITE);
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  testdrawroundrect();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  testfillroundrect();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  testdrawtriangle();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  testfilltriangle();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw the first ~12 characters in the font
  testdrawchar();
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // draw scrolling text
  testscrolltext();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();

  // text display tests
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0,0);
  display.println("Hello, world!");
  display.setTextColor(BLACK, WHITE); // 'inverted' text
  display.println(3.141592);
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.print("0x"); display.println(0xDEADBEEF, HEX);
  display.display();
  delay(2000);

  // miniature bitmap display
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.drawBitmap(30, 16,  logo16_glcd_bmp, 16, 16, 1);
  display.display();

  // invert the display
  display.invertDisplay(true);
  delay(1000); 
  display.invertDisplay(false);
  delay(1000); 

  // draw a bitmap icon and 'animate' movement
  testdrawbitmap(logo16_glcd_bmp, LOGO16_GLCD_HEIGHT, LOGO16_GLCD_WIDTH);
}


void loop() {

}


void testdrawbitmap(const uint8_t *bitmap, uint8_t w, uint8_t h) {
  uint8_t icons[NUMFLAKES][3];

  // initialize
  for (uint8_t f=0; f< NUMFLAKES; f++) {
    icons[f][XPOS] = random(display.width());
    icons[f][YPOS] = 0;
    icons[f][DELTAY] = random(5) + 1;

    Serial.print("x: ");
    Serial.print(icons[f][XPOS], DEC);
    Serial.print(" y: ");
    Serial.print(icons[f][YPOS], DEC);
    Serial.print(" dy: ");
    Serial.println(icons[f][DELTAY], DEC);
  }

  while (1) {
    // draw each icon
    for (uint8_t f=0; f< NUMFLAKES; f++) {
      display.drawBitmap(icons[f][XPOS], icons[f][YPOS], logo16_glcd_bmp, w, h, WHITE);
    }
    display.display();
    delay(200);

    // then erase it + move it
    for (uint8_t f=0; f< NUMFLAKES; f++) {
      display.drawBitmap(icons[f][XPOS], icons[f][YPOS],  logo16_glcd_bmp, w, h, BLACK);
      // move it
      icons[f][YPOS] += icons[f][DELTAY];
      // if its gone, reinit
      if (icons[f][YPOS] > display.height()) {
    icons[f][XPOS] = random(display.width());
    icons[f][YPOS] = 0;
    icons[f][DELTAY] = random(5) + 1;
      }
    }
   }
}


void testdrawchar(void) {
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0,0);

  for (uint8_t i=0; i < 168; i++) {
    if (i == '\n') continue;
    display.write(i);
    if ((i > 0) && (i % 21 == 0))
      display.println();
  }    
  display.display();
}

void testdrawcircle(void) {
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.height(); i+=2) {
    display.drawCircle(display.width()/2, display.height()/2, i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
}

void testfillrect(void) {
  uint8_t color = 1;
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.height()/2; i+=3) {
    // alternate colors
    display.fillRect(i, i, display.width()-i*2, display.height()-i*2, color%2);
    display.display();
    color++;
  }
}

void testdrawtriangle(void) {
  for (int16_t i=0; i<min(display.width(),display.height())/2; i+=5) {
    display.drawTriangle(display.width()/2, display.height()/2-i,
                     display.width()/2-i, display.height()/2+i,
                     display.width()/2+i, display.height()/2+i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
}

void testfilltriangle(void) {
  uint8_t color = WHITE;
  for (int16_t i=min(display.width(),display.height())/2; i>0; i-=5) {
    display.fillTriangle(display.width()/2, display.height()/2-i,
                     display.width()/2-i, display.height()/2+i,
                     display.width()/2+i, display.height()/2+i, WHITE);
    if (color == WHITE) color = BLACK;
    else color = WHITE;
    display.display();
  }
}

void testdrawroundrect(void) {
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.height()/2-2; i+=2) {
    display.drawRoundRect(i, i, display.width()-2*i, display.height()-2*i, display.height()/4, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
}

void testfillroundrect(void) {
  uint8_t color = WHITE;
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.height()/2-2; i+=2) {
    display.fillRoundRect(i, i, display.width()-2*i, display.height()-2*i, display.height()/4, color);
    if (color == WHITE) color = BLACK;
    else color = WHITE;
    display.display();
  }
}

void testdrawrect(void) {
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.height()/2; i+=2) {
    display.drawRect(i, i, display.width()-2*i, display.height()-2*i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
}

void testdrawline() {  
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.width(); i+=4) {
    display.drawLine(0, 0, i, display.height()-1, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.height(); i+=4) {
    display.drawLine(0, 0, display.width()-1, i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  delay(250);

  display.clearDisplay();
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.width(); i+=4) {
    display.drawLine(0, display.height()-1, i, 0, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  for (int16_t i=display.height()-1; i>=0; i-=4) {
    display.drawLine(0, display.height()-1, display.width()-1, i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  delay(250);

  display.clearDisplay();
  for (int16_t i=display.width()-1; i>=0; i-=4) {
    display.drawLine(display.width()-1, display.height()-1, i, 0, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  for (int16_t i=display.height()-1; i>=0; i-=4) {
    display.drawLine(display.width()-1, display.height()-1, 0, i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  delay(250);

  display.clearDisplay();
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.height(); i+=4) {
    display.drawLine(display.width()-1, 0, 0, i, WHITE);
    display.display();
  }
  for (int16_t i=0; i<display.width(); i+=4) {
    display.drawLine(display.width()-1, 0, i, display.height()-1, WHITE); 
    display.display();
  }
  delay(250);
}

void testscrolltext(void) {
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(10,0);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.println("scroll");
  display.display();

  display.startscrollright(0x00, 0x0F);
  delay(2000);
  display.stopscroll();
  delay(1000);
  display.startscrollleft(0x00, 0x0F);
  delay(2000);
  display.stopscroll();
  delay(1000);    
  display.startscrolldiagright(0x00, 0x07);
  delay(2000);
  display.startscrolldiagleft(0x00, 0x07);
  delay(2000);
  display.stopscroll();
}
```

Comment: I think I have the same problem like this link 

http://www.electroschematics.com/11150/cheap-oled-displays-arduino/

but the case is using I2P 

and I didn't understand how it resolve the bug

Comment: Nobody wants to watch videos. Clearly type and post exactly what the problem is, as well as, your code so far, if any.

Comment: Check the connection. That does not look like SPI.

Comment: @WillyLotus -  This question doesn't clearly ask a question.  You have an issue, but its not clear which display has the fault, you say left, but from what perspective.  There is no indication of any make or model numbers of the faulty unit.  You imply that the two displays are not the same or one has a pin missing.  Please can you try and improve the question and keep all the information on this site as external links may not be trust worthy.  Sorry, I'm not trying to be horrible, I'm actually trying to help you get a better answer faster.

Comment: Are they both the same model? Both the same resolution? Both the same driver chip?

Answer (score 0):

Check the connections with that required by the software/library. If you intend to use SPI the pins on Arduino Uno are:

```
SS   10
MOSI 11
MISO 12
SCK  13
```

You connections above are:

```
VCC             => 5V
D0(OLED_CLK)    => 10 (SPI SS ??)
D(OLED_MOSI)    => 9  
RES(OLED_RESET) => 13 (SPI SCK ??)
D/C(OLED_DC)    => 11 (SPI MOSI ??)
CS（OLED_CS）     => 12 (SPI MISO ??)
GND             => GND (??)
```

That is not correct for SPI. Post link to library, oled hardware, and snippet of your code for more help.

It is more than the video that is out of focus :)

Cheers!

Comment: For the OP, slave select can be whatever pin one defines while writing the library, that means if the library supports it you can use multiple SPI slaves (multiple, different screens at one for example) but it's usually not that easy (depends of the frame of reference) unless someone has done it already and uploaded the code.